# SLIM PHP PHINX cannot do a migration to a MySQL container

Tags: php, mysql, docker, slim, phinx

I am trying to do a migration with PHINX in a database with a MySQL container, but getting the following issue.

`PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused in /var/www/html/vendor/robmorgan/phinx/src/Phinx/Db/Adapter/PdoAdapter.php:86`

This is my phinx.php:

```
<?php

require './vendor/autoload.php';

return
[
    'paths' => [
        'migrations' => 'database/migrations',
        'seeds' => '/database/seeds'
    ],
    'migration_base_class' => '\Migrations\Migration',
    'environments' => [
        'default_environment' => 'dev',
        'default_database' => 'dev',
        'dev' => [
            'adapter' => 'mysql',
            'host' => '127.0.0.1',
            'name' => 'db_slim',
            'user' => 'db_slim',
            'pass' => 'root',
        ]
    ]
];
```

Migration class:

```
<?php

namespace Migrations;

use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as Capsule;
use Phinx\Migration\AbstractMigration;

class Migration extends AbstractMigration
{
    /** @var \Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager $capsule */
    public $capsule;
    /** @var \Illuminate\Database\Schema\Builder $capsule */
    public $schema;

    public function init()
    {
        $this->capsule = new Capsule;
        $this->capsule->addConnection([
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => '127.0.0.1',
            'database' => 'db_slim',
            'username' => 'db_slim',
            'password' => 'root',
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        ]);

        $this->capsule->bootEloquent();
        $this->capsule->setAsGlobal();
        $this->schema = $this->capsule->schema();
    }
}
```

Create table instruction:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

use Migrations\Migration;

final class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Change Method.
     *
     * Write your reversible migrations using this method.
     *
     * More information on writing migrations is available here:
     * https://book.cakephp.org/phinx/0/en/migrations.html#the-change-method
     *
     * Remember to call "create()" or "update()" and NOT "save()" when working
     * with the Table class.
     */
    public function change()
    {
        $this->schema->create('users', function (Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments("id");
            $table->string("name");
            $table->string("email");
            $table->string("password");
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
}
```

Docker container:

```
mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7.29
    container_name: mysql_slim
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: db_slim
      MYSQL_USER: db_slim
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    networks:
      - php-challenge
    volumes:
      - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
```

I can access the container DB with tools like a workbench, php-storm database tab, I don't know why I try do execute phinx.php migrate is getting the issue, for some reason, I think that my conn values (host, etc) do not work.

I've tried to do the same command migration outside the container (with a local MySQL env) and works, is there another way to solve or connect to the MySQL container?

Comment: Is the php migration file executed within the container? if not, then the localhost points to the host where the code is executed, not to the container.

Comment: i'm using the container to run docker-compose exec php /var/www/html/vendor/bin/phinx migrate -c /var/www/html/phinx.php

Comment: Phinx itself is a migration tool and provides its own migrations helper methods. so you don't need to set up a second db connection using eloquent. The connection issue is a network or credential issue. Try to use "localhost".

Comment: @odan connection refused is not a credential issue. This error means that there is no mysql listening on the given port or a firewall reects the connection.